# Rule not found in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have taken export of a db from a computer that has auth tables and imported the same in another computer which have the codes in place in htdocs folder. But when I'm trying to access the data, I'm getting error - Rule not found. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Auth Rule query specified by SiZE cannot be executed.
[image]

Also, I don't have any entry in auth_rule table.
[image]

In the computer from which I've taken the export, there's also no auth_rule entry.. There I don't get this error.

Comment: Execute this query: `SELECT * FROM {{%auth_rule}} WHERE name='s_create_product';` and show it result.

Comment: Hi SiZE, I have no entry in auth_rule table. There's no entry in auth_rule table from where I have taken the export. Also, the query you mentioned cannot be executed. I've added screen pint of it. Please have a look.

Comment: Looks like the backup program that created the exported the DB has some issue. Because I've tried with another backup taken from other program, and it works fine. Though I'm facing other issues. I'll ask in a separate thread.

Comment: `{{%auth_rule}} ` is a Yii2 feature to use tables with prefix. I meant that you would replace it with the name of your table, if necessary add a prefix.